# Android Download from server to SD card fails

Tags: android, file, pdf, download

Iam trying to download a pdf file from a server and trying to store it in SD card location after creating a folder. But the problem is, Iam unable to see neither the folder or file when i check through the SD card in my computer. mkdir() returns true but i cant see the file/folder. What am i doing wrong

Manifest File:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
             List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             Log.i(TAG, "Filename: " + Filename);

             param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename", Filename));
             post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);


             InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
             Log.i(TAG, "InputStream Read from URL");


             if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200){

                 Log.i(TAG, "Inside Read");

                 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"filedownload");
                 if(folder.exists()){
                     folder.delete();
                 }
                 folder.mkdir();


                 File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"filedownload"+File.separator+Filename);


                 if(f2.canWrite()){


                     Log.i(TAG, "File can  be written");
                     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f2);

                     fos.flush();
                     int read = 0;
                     byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                     int count=0;




                     while((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0){
                         fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            count++;
                     }
                     Log.i(TAG, "File Size:"+fos.toString());
                     fos.close();
                     is.close();
                 }
```

Comment: Manifest File:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: unplug-plug your usb cable

Comment: You are deleting the folder when it exists. That is no good approach. Moreover if the folder contains a file it will not be deleted. Instead call mkdirs if the folder does NOT exist and check the return value. You said that mkdirs returns true but in your code you are not checking that. You use canWrite on a non existing file. Instead you should do that on the directory. Please tell which Logs you see. The file size log is wrong.

Comment: HI greenapps, Thanks a lot for your response.

I have made changes as per your suggestion:

Comment: File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"new");
     
     
  if(!folder.exists()){
      Log.i(TAG,"Create Directory :"+String.valueOf(folder.mkdir()));}

     
     Log.i(TAG,"Give Write Perm :"+String.valueOf(folder.canWrite()));

     Log.i(TAG,"Give Read Perm :"+String.valueOf(folder.canRead()));

     Log.i(TAG,"Give Execute Perm :"+String.valueOf(folder.canExecute()));

Comment: Log:
03-14 06:19:54.772: I/MyTest(7594): Create Directory :true
03-14 06:19:54.772: I/MyTest(7594): Give Write Perm :true
03-14 06:19:54.772: I/MyTest(7594): Give Read Perm :true
03-14 06:19:54.772: I/MyTest(7594): Give Execute Perm :true

Comment: Still iam unable to see the folder..Please help